# E: Unable to locate package libicu-dev , libicu-dev' returned a non-zero code: 100

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

I am working on a php docker application.Am facing an error while trying docker-compose up command. Trying to connect a php application to mysql.

My docker compose file

```
web:
 build: .
 command: php -S 0.0.0.0:8000 -t /app
 links:
- db
 ports:
- "8000:8000"
volumes:
- ./app:/app
db:
 image: mysql
 ports:
 - "3306:3306"
environment:
 MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
 MYSQL_USER: dev
 MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123456
 MYSQL_DATABASE: myapp
```

Am getting this error: E: Unable to locate package libicu-dev
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y libicu-dev' returned a non-zero code: 100

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This might be because these are https sources.

Can you invoke

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
```

before the command

```
/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y libicu-dev
```

is executed?

See 
[apt-get update' returned a non-zero code: 100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38002543/apt-get-update-returned-a-non-zero-code-100)

Answer (score 1):

1. apt update
2. (optional) apt purge libicu-dev
3. apt install libicu-dev