# "E: Package 'php-soap' has no installation candidate" on php:7.0-fpm Docker image. Exit with code: 100

Tags: php, docker, soap, docker-compose

I suppose the title says it all... I have a container set from php:7.0-fpm image.

In the Dockerfile, I run, `apt-get update && apt-get install -y php-soap`. However, it fails and returned `100` as exit code. Additionally, there is `E: Package 'php-soap' has no installation candidate` as well.

Based on this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38002543/apt-get-update-returned-a-non-zero-code-100), I need to install `apt-transport-https`. I put that to be installed in the Dockerfile, but still the same error. What should I do?

Comment: I just saw same issue from Dockerfile build on Travis CI. Build works fine locally, however. With `php:5.6-apache` image

Answer (score 9):

The FPM image brings php from the source. When you run `apt-get install php-soap`, you get php from APT, which comes with a different version.
At least that understood.

Provisional fix:

```
RUN rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/no-debian-php
```

In the future, avoid using `apt-get` to install php dependencies.

Comment: Still don't get what you meant. I thought my option is to use Ubuntu/Debian image. Or, someway I install PHP Soap package. I think you suggest the latter. So, how can I install PHP deps that usually come from `apt-get`?

Comment: This worked for me. Was getting 'not a candidate' errors from apt-get calls on debian. Installed this line of code above my apt-get calls and everything worked.

Comment: man, dont even how to thanks, you saved me after investigating for several hours , also eg here - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383999/why-are-some-packages-not-available-in-my-debian-jessie-installation

Answer (score 3):

This fixed my problem. In your `php-fpm\Dockerfile` change this:

`RUN if [ ${INSTALL_SOAP} = true ]; then \
    # Install the soap extension
    apt-get update -yqq && \
    apt-get -y install libxml2-dev php-soap && \
    docker-php-ext-install soap \
;fi`

Into this:

`RUN if [ ${INSTALL_SOAP} = true ]; then \
    # Install the soap extension
    rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/no-debian-php && \
    apt-get update -yqq && \
    apt-get -y install libxml2-dev php-soap && \
    docker-php-ext-install soap \
;fi`

Also see [this](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1476) issue.