# Docker - "The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install nodejs' returned a non-zero code: 100"

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to build a Docker image for my API with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet AS build-env  
ARG source  
RUN echo "source: $source"  
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash
RUN apt-get install nodejs
RUN node -v
RUN npm -v
# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

#Copy everything else & build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
EXPOSE 80  
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "API_App.dll"]
```

However, when I run the docker build command, I keep getting the following error:

```
Unable to locate package nodejs
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install nodejs returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Can someone tell me why I am getting this error?

Node Version: `8.11.3`
npm Version: `5.6.0`

Comment: Check this answer.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38002543/apt-get-update-returned-a-non-zero-code-100/38004106#38004106

Comment: It worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You may occasionally experience some cache issues when the live repositories you’re pulling data from have changed.

To fix this, modify the Dockerfile to do a cleanup and update of the sources before you install any new packages.

```
...
# clean and update sources
RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update
...
```

This answer is from [digitalocean-issue](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-debug-and-fix-common-docker-issues)