# At least one invalid signature was encountered

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, skaffold

I am trying to build and deploy microservices images to a single-node Kubernetes cluster running on my development machine using minikube. I am using the cloud-native microservices demo application Online Boutique by Google to understand the use of technologies like Kubernetes, Istio etc.

Link to github repo: [microservices-demo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/microservices-demo)

While following the installation process, and on running command `skaffold run` to build and deploy my application, I get some errors:

```
Step 10/11 : RUN apt-get -qq update     && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends         curl
 ---> Running in 43d61232617c
W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease' is not signed.
W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease' is not signed.
W: GPG error: http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
E: The repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease' is not signed.
failed to build: couldn't build "loadgenerator": unable to stream build output: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get -qq update     && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends         curl' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

I receive these errors when trying to build loadgenerator.
How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 244, accepted):

There are a few reasons why you encounter these errors:

1. There might be an issue with the existing cache and/or disc space. In order to fix it you need to clear the APT cache by executing: `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo apt-get update`.
2. The same goes with existing docker images. Execute: `docker image prune -f` and `docker container prune -f` in order to remove unused data and free disc space. Executing `docker image prune -f` will delete all the unused images. To delete some selective images of large size, run `docker images` and identify the images you want to remove, and then run `docker rmi -f <IMAGE-ID1> <IMAGE-ID2> <IMAGE-ID3>`.
3. If you don't care about the security risks, you can try to run the `apt-get` command with the `--allow-unauthenticated` or `--allow-insecure-repositories` flag. According to the [docs](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt-get.8.en.html):

> Ignore if packages can't be authenticated and don't prompt about it.
> This can be useful while working with local repositories, but is a
> huge security risk if data authenticity isn't ensured in another way
> by the user itself.

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: Hi, I have tried all the three methods, and it still does not work, is there anything else I could possibly do? Thanks!

Comment: @SaranyaGupta Have you tried that with `sudo`? Does it print the same error?

Comment: Yes! I have used sudo with all three methods.

Comment: If there are no space issues (check with `df -h`) there might be one more thing: run `rm -rf /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/*`. It will remove old gpg repositories that could potentially cause some conflicts.

Comment: Caused by being out of diskspace (fixed by pruning with docker).

Comment: `docker-compose down -v --rmi all --remove-orphans` did the trick for me.

Comment: For me, `docker image prune -f` was enough !

Comment: `docker system prune` worked for me. Had 20 GB of build cache.

Comment: I was getting this error in Azure Devops building by Docker image. Using `--allow-unauthenticated` with apt-get worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: I encountered the problem while building docker images and the second point worked for me.

Comment: `docker images | awk '{print $3}' | xargs -I{} docker rmi -f {}`

Comment: Can someone explain WHY this error is caused by low disk space? Why does apt throw this unhelpful error when disk space is low?

Comment: I tried all of these, but still no go.  `docker system df` showed ~50 Gbytes of images still.  I needed to do a `docker image prune -a` to get rid of them, and finally get things working again.

Answer (score 231):

I had this same issue and none of the previous responses saying to prune images or containers worked. The reason was that my Docker Build Cache was taking up the bulk of the space. Running the below command fixed the issue:

```
docker system prune
```

You can then check to see if it worked by running:

```
docker system df
```

UPDATE:

The above command will clear the whole Docker system. If you want to clear only the build cache, you can do it with the below command (credit to [saraf.gahl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3219421/saraf-gahl)):

```sh
docker builder prune
```

Comment: Thanks! This was a pointer in the right direction. Note you can also clear the build cache directly - `docker builder prune`. :)

Comment: Added a note to this effect. Thanks!

Comment: I had this issue on my `mac` while builder a `docker` image and I had no idea what was going on. This worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: This was very helpful! I didn't relate "invalid signature" with disc space issue, thanks! However I would recommend to move `docker system prune` in your answer lower as a final step as usually it may be better to clear only build cache and not whole docker system (which will remove also volume data). In most cases `docker builder prune` should be fair enough.

Comment: As per my comment above, I needed to add `-a` to get rid of everything (and get things working again)

Answer (score 57):

The reason I usually see this is because docker has run out of disk space, which is frustrating because the error gives little indication that this is the problem. First try cleaning up images and containers you don't need using the `prune` command https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/.

[image: warning] **this would delete all your images**

```
$ docker image prune 
$ docker container prune
```

If you have a lot of images accumulated and want to remove all of them that aren't associated with an existing container try:

```
$ docker image prune -a
```

Or you can remove only older images:

```
$ docker image prune -a --filter "until=24h"
```

Finally, on MacOS, where Docker runs inside a dedicated VM, you may need to increase the disk available to Docker from the Docker Desktop application (Settings -> Resources -> Advanced -> Disk image size).

Comment: this works for me under minikube system

Comment: worked on mac with dockerdesktop - sad there is no clear error.

Comment: It is nuts that apt-get fails in this way when it runs out of disk space. In a container, this manifested in `df` showing the root filesystem being 100% in use. On Docker Desktop for Mac, clicking the bug icon in the dashboard title bar and then "Clean / Purge data" did the trick.

Answer (score 38):

@Jack Kawell got it right.

```
docker builder prune
```

This command does the trick.
Beware of the command "*docker system prune*" as this would delete all your images (very destructive).
The builder prune only deletes the build cache that is where your have all your previous (cached) builds steps.

Comment: It should be the accepted answer because it focuses directly on the real cause of the error.

Answer (score 24):

I had the same problem. It looks like it was lack of space. I've removed old images and it started to work.

`$ docker images`

Select the ones you don't care anymore (to delete).

`$ docker rmi <image_id>`

The following command filter the dangling images and remove those.

`docker rmi $(docker images -q --filter "dangling=true")`

Comment: The same for me

Answer (score 16):

I think that is related to some LSM component of the docker official image (in this case armhf) and exec/capabilities  permissions. In this simple case *sid* flavour is unable to handle time corectly. And this related to the certificate check, is the cause of invalid signature. It happends too in ubuntu focal.

```
# docker run -it debian:buster /bin/date
Sun Nov 15 11:30:44 UTC 2020
# docker run -it debian:sid /bin/date 
Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 UTC 1970
```

Comment: THIS. Omg how did you figure this out.

Comment: Upgrading pi kernel to buster, upgrading to docker-ce and building my own image from debootstrap with qemu, see comment below.

Comment: Thank you so much! Same issue with e.g. `balenalib/raspberry-pi-node`.
Using `debian:buster`, I can now build my Dockerfile without any errors.

Comment: thanks a lot! had the same issue trying to build a docker image for raspberry pi using a latest image for some tag that used bullseye as its base, switching to buster fixed the issue.

Comment: But how to solve it?

Answer (score 12):

None of these worked for me. This command did the trick though:

```
docker volume prune
```

Literally had 249GB worth of volumes that I was able to reclaim.

Comment: did not helped for me

Answer (score 11):

I tried a few of the above answers, and none of them worked for me. The real trigger was when I used `--allow-unauthenticated` and `--allow-insecure-repositories` from [@Wytrzymały Wiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11560878/wytrzyma%C5%82y-wiktor)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62510927/5738), and I got a notification showing

```
tar: ./conffiles: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: ./control: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: ./md5sums: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: ./postinst: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: .: Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

This lead me down a route where I found [this post](https://blog.samcater.com/fix-workaround-rpi4-docker-libseccomp2-docker-20/) which suggested that the issue may be where libseccomp2 was outdated.

The fix there was to do:

```
# Get signing keys to verify the new packages, otherwise they will not install
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 04EE7237B7D453EC 648ACFD622F3D138

# Add the Buster backport repository to apt sources.list
echo 'deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib non-free' | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian-backports.list

sudo apt update ; sudo apt install libseccomp2 -t buster-backports
```

Note that this assumes that you're using Raspbian and a version of docker after 19.04

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it for me. ( php:8.0-apache-bullseye container in a raspbian docker environment )

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the issue on my Raspberry Pi as well. Should have a lot more upvotes.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I was trying to run a Docker `debian:stable` (bullseye at the moment) in a Raspberry PI with a `buster` distribution of the OS.

Changed to `debian:buster`and it worked

Hope this will help someone out there

Comment: This helped me quite a bit, even when using: --allow-unauthenticated --allow-insecure-repositories, I was getting several "not signed error". Looks like it is a debian stable (bullseye) problem, but with debian:buster works fine, still don't know why but happy to have a workaround for it. Thanks!

Comment: @ArgiesDario glad it helped someone, you’re most welcome

Answer (score 2):

@BoyArmy_89 solves my similar problem; I tried all the other solutions but only the following worked:

```
docker volume prune
```

Answer (score 1):

> At least one invalid signature was encountered

The error suggests that one of the files in `/var/lib/apt/lists` consist at least one invalid/corrupted signature (could be the result of `apt-key` misuse or something else).

Try to run Apt update with the debug messages:

```
apt-get -oDebug::pkgAcquire::Worker=1 update
```

which should point you to the corrupted file, e.g.

> 0% [Working] <- gpgv:400%20URI%20Failure%0aMessage:%20At%20least%20one%20invalid%20signature%20was%20encountered.%0aURI:%20gpgv:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/CorruptedFile_InRelease

Edit the file, find and remove the corrupted parts, or remove the whole file, so it can be recreated.

Answer (score 1):

> The actual problem:

The actual problem was with the docker version. Upgrading the docker from version 19 to 20 solved the issue.

> The work around if you cannot upgrade docker:

I had the same issue when I was upgrading PHP from `php:7.4-fpm` to `php:8.3-fpm`. I managed to solve the issue by changing the image in the Dockerfile

- From:

```
FROM php:8.3-fpm
```

- To:

```
FROM php:8.3-fpm-bullseye
```

I used the specific bullseye image in order to have access to the packages.

*Note the bookworm version as well*.

Answer (score 0):

Make your own sid image in x64

```
# variables
$WORKPLACE=/space_change_me
$BASEIMG=debian:buster
$TAG=my/debian
$RELEASE=sid
$PLATFORM=arm

# multiarch preparation
apt-get update
apt-get -y install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg lsb-release
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
apt-get update
apt-get -y install qemu binfmt-support qemu-user-static docker-ce byobu make
export DOCKER_CLI_EXPERIMENTAL=enabled

#build image
docker run  -i --rm -v $WORKPLACE:/data $BASEIMG /bin/bash  << EOF
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" 
apt-get -y update
apt-get -y install debootstrap
debootstrap --verbose --include=iputils-ping --arch $PLATFORM $RELEASE /data/$RELEASE-$PLATFORM $REPO
chroot /data/$RELEASE-$PLATFORM/ /bin/bash << SEOF 
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive"
apt-get -y update
apt-get -y upgrade
apt-get -y clean
SEOF
rm -R /data/$RELEASE-$PLATFORM/debootstrap
EOF

cd $WORKPLACE/$RELEASE-$PLATFORM
tar cpf - . | docker import - $TAG:$RELEASE-$PLATFORM --platform $PLATFORM
docker save $TAG:$RELEASE-$PLATFORM  > debian-$RELEASE-$PLATFORM.tar
```

You can load later in the arm host with

```
cat debian-$RELEASE-$PLATFORM.tar |docker load
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this error can also appear depending on the debian mirror server that you're connecting to. I got the error several times, then once I turned on a VPN with a server in a different city, no more problems.

https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/898#issuecomment-539234070