# unable to build the image from container, unknown what the error is

Tags: docker, flask

I am not able to build the Docker image and i am not sure what is causing the issue.

I think the issue is coming from the OCR package installation.
I think the issue is coming from this part of the Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y poppler-utils tesseract-ocr \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

This has been working for about two months now its not working.

this is the command that i am running to build the image::

```
docker container prune
docker image prune -a
docker network prune
docker volume prune
docker system prune

docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

this is the Dockerfile:

```
# Dockerfile

FROM python:3.11.3

USER root

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y poppler-utils tesseract-ocr \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Environment specific requirements
ARG ENVIRONMENT
ENV CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT=$ENVIRONMENT
COPY requirements-${ENVIRONMENT}.txt /app/
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements-${ENVIRONMENT}.txt


# COPY requirements-aws.txt /app/
# RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements-aws.txt

EXPOSE 80

ENV NAME World

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

this is the docker-compose.yml::

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        ENVIRONMENT: local  # when running locally
        # ENVIRONMENT: aws    # when running on aws
        
    volumes:
      - /Users/juan/Desktop/dev/code/docwise-backend:/app
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    environment:
      - FLASK_ENV=development
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
      - .env

    depends_on:
      - redis

  worker:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        ENVIRONMENT: local  # when running locally
        # ENVIRONMENT: aws    # when running on aws
    volumes:
      - /Users/juan/Desktop/dev/code/docwise-backend:/app
    command: celery -A app.celery worker --loglevel=info
    environment:
      - FLASK_ENV=development
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
      - .env

    depends_on:
      - redis

  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

this is what i am running on the terminal and its output:::

```
juan@192 docwise-backend % docker container prune
docker image prune -a
docker network prune
docker volume prune
docker system prune

docker-compose build
docker-compose up
WARNING! This will remove all stopped containers.
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
Total reclaimed space: 0B
WARNING! This will remove all images without at least one container associated to them.
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
Deleted Images:
untagged: redis:alpine
untagged: redis@sha256:ef3296cb1b3a7eb40f2a992a398777a1c0b5b21df44f1a5bef84067f772daf54
deleted: sha256:8b8f8a322bdc7e1df2d6db1e418510bd4d5c01964f5e04d6bb5f022cf1eba245
deleted: sha256:e2df09f25de02bfee0b85bffa28b07f7266602ee8355ac9d7cff0b1dd98d31e5
deleted: sha256:a316c3a65ee6ffb01ef8ae19798f43e72d2373b54fbbb702d7ce4b44ad11eea1
deleted: sha256:71b348d6ece5a0c34cb5d5a82fc65809638179dde84f6cdb73a1b6746a8b228e
deleted: sha256:18a94920b351a9934301a733f481ab606b01642d11122e15b45eab0e717bba33
deleted: sha256:ba87a2d269bda2d5d6db4216d9e0e5752bc10825cfed90fdc291b9b0bf7ba90a
deleted: sha256:b2191e2be29d816fa6fbde954316d54e10df9a882c7ca38e3e087d9cbca49fe6

Total reclaimed space: 38.55MB
WARNING! This will remove all custom networks not used by at least one container.
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
WARNING! This will remove anonymous local volumes not used by at least one container.
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
Total reclaimed space: 0B
WARNING! This will remove:
  - all stopped containers
  - all networks not used by at least one container
  - all dangling images
  - all dangling build cache

Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
Deleted build cache objects:
hm924g20vpax7e1vcv5qd68b9
m04w08bg8bq8syeatuwa8ee3f
3y5v3yqrehdx1xxtsa6qhehv4
j4fq4j1dmh7hs4irpxni3m1vl
as4fsivoo58ts6fgaiyhfntqb
706o9nq0a5f05vxggpidnkc3m
4ytjq6ltpuj2fmuj6norxlx1y
51ajydk3yqslby64ilf6g1g3n
ewuxp6cn71z75pxx27k7fhmaq
woc4dtvjwnkc1ibwatlxgg3um
114z12lh2o0zx6s61xxbek646
rovos62w36hnjmy6d9yxly22r
wh6zjs0e6u0x2g8iwfqls4jj2
zn8xo1v7y9mox1p5jso1j68da
b19zzakorizgvvem3iq4vy2vl
rrxrsrmwuipo4bsrlosb19fn7

Total reclaimed space: 80.9MB
[+] Building 3.5s (12/18)                                                                                                               docker:desktop-linux
 => [web internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [web internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 662B                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [worker internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.11.3                                                                                 1.9s
 => [worker internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [worker internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 662B                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [web auth] library/python:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                       0.0s
 => [web 1/6] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.11.3@sha256:3a619e3c96fd4c5fc5e1998fd4dcb1f1403eb90c4c6409c70d7e80b9468df7df                              0.2s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/python:3.11.3@sha256:3a619e3c96fd4c5fc5e1998fd4dcb1f1403eb90c4c6409c70d7e80b9468df7df                                  0.0s
 => => sha256:3a619e3c96fd4c5fc5e1998fd4dcb1f1403eb90c4c6409c70d7e80b9468df7df 2.14kB / 2.14kB                                                          0.0s
 => => sha256:1918a277862c33ee6f35b696867ca414a014f2b63f1e257986a3f480c9da5edc 7.54kB / 7.54kB                                                          0.0s
 => => sha256:de5aeca5458519a772e9b344d3c1ac16a1be52eab179cf2a28a31382dd1018f1 2.01kB / 2.01kB                                                          0.0s
 => [worker internal] load build context                                                                                                                0.6s
 => => transferring context: 27.34MB                                                                                                                    0.6s
 => [web internal] load build context                                                                                                                   0.6s
 => => transferring context: 27.34MB                                                                                                                    0.6s
 => [worker 2/6] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                           0.1s
 => [worker 3/6] ADD . /app                                                                                                                             0.3s
 => ERROR [worker 4/6] RUN apt-get update     && apt-get install -y poppler-utils tesseract-ocr     && apt-get clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/  0.6s
------                                                                                                                                                       
 > [worker 4/6] RUN apt-get update     && apt-get install -y poppler-utils tesseract-ocr     && apt-get clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*:            
0.226 Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease [116 kB]
0.286 Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease
0.286   At least one invalid signature was encountered.
0.393 Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease [48.4 kB]
0.440 Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
0.440   At least one invalid signature was encountered.
0.549 Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease [44.1 kB]
0.599 Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
0.599   At least one invalid signature was encountered.
0.604 Reading package lists...
0.613 W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
0.613 E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease' is not signed.
0.613 W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
0.613 E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease' is not signed.
0.613 W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
0.613 E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease' is not signed.
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update     && apt-get install -y poppler-utils tesseract-ocr     && apt-get clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
[+] Running 7/7
 ✔ redis 6 layers [⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿]      0B/0B      Pulled                                                                                                       4.1s 
   ✔ 9fda8d8052c6 Pull complete                                                                                                                         1.2s 
   ✔ 8808541ccd68 Pull complete                                                                                                                         1.2s 
   ✔ fe6a7a1ce6c8 Pull complete                                                                                                                         1.4s 
   ✔ 7376bb4ed18c Pull complete                                                                                                                         2.3s 
   ✔ c8e6786fe2c5 Pull complete                                                                                                                         2.3s 
   ✔ d75acb01af49 Pull complete                                                                                                                         2.3s 
[+] Building 0.9s (11/17)                                                                                                               docker:desktop-linux
 => [worker internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [worker internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 662B                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [web internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 662B                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [web internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [worker internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.11.3                                                                                 0.3s
 => [web 1/6] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.11.3@sha256:3a619e3c96fd4c5fc5e1998fd4dcb1f1403eb90c4c6409c70d7e80b9468df7df                              0.0s
 => [worker internal] load build context                                                                                                                0.1s
 => => transferring context: 329.72kB                                                                                                                   0.1s
 => [web internal] load build context                                                                                                                   0.1s
 => => transferring context: 329.72kB                                                                                                                   0.1s
 => CACHED [worker 2/6] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [worker 3/6] ADD . /app                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => ERROR [worker 4/6] RUN apt-get update     && apt-get install -y poppler-utils tesseract-ocr     && apt-get clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/  0.3s
------                                                                                                                                                       
 > [worker 4/6] RUN apt-get update     && apt-get install -y poppler-utils tesseract-ocr     && apt-get clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*:            
0.127 Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease [116 kB]                                                                                         
0.144 Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease [48.4 kB]                                                                      
0.151 Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease [44.1 kB]                                                                                
0.185 Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease                                                                                                  
0.185   At least one invalid signature was encountered.
0.221 Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
0.221   At least one invalid signature was encountered.
0.256 Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
0.256   At least one invalid signature was encountered.
0.259 Reading package lists...
0.267 W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
0.267 E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease' is not signed.
0.267 W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
0.267 E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease' is not signed.
0.267 W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
0.267 E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease' is not signed.
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update     && apt-get install -y poppler-utils tesseract-ocr     && apt-get clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
juan@192 docwise-backend %
```

I am super confused where the error is came from.

chatgpt is not helping.

I found a similar issue on this website::
[Atleast one invalid signature was encountered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62473932/atleast-one-invalid-signature-was-encountered/64843925#64843925)

That led me to this stackoverflow issue:
https://github.com/debuerreotype/docker-debian-artifacts/issues/122

from the Stackoverflow question, they provided the following guidance, I tried it but didnt get very far::

```
I think that is related to some LSM component of the docker official image (in this case armhf) and exec/capabilities permissions. In this simple case sid flavour is unable to handle time corectly. And this related to the certificate check, is the cause of invalid signature. It happends too in ubuntu focal.

# docker run -it debian:buster /bin/date
Sun Nov 15 11:30:44 UTC 2020
# docker run -it debian:sid /bin/date 
Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 UTC 1970
```

This is what i tried running on my computer::

```
juan@192 docwise-backend % 
juan@192 docwise-backend % 
juan@192 docwise-backend % docker run -it --rm arm32v7/debian:buster-slim /bin/date  
Mon Sep 11 20:47:30 UTC 2023
juan@192 docwise-backend % docker run -it --rm arm32v7/debian:bullseye-slim /bin/date
Mon Sep 11 20:47:38 UTC 2023
juan@192 docwise-backend % docker-compose up
[+] Building 2.2s (12/18)                                                                                                               docker:desktop-linux
 => [worker internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                             0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 662B                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [worker internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [web internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.11.3                                                                                    1.7s
 => [web internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [web internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 662B                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [worker auth] library/python:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                    0.0s
 => [worker internal] load build context                                                                                                                0.2s
 => => transferring context: 329.72kB                                                                                                                   0.1s
 => [web 1/6] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.11.3@sha256:3a619e3c96fd4c5fc5e1998fd4dcb1f1403eb90c4c6409c70d7e80b9468df7df                              0.0s
 => [web internal] load build context                                                                                                                   0.2s
 => => transferring context: 329.72kB                                                                                                                   0.2s
 => CACHED [worker 2/6] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [worker 3/6] ADD . /app                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => ERROR [worker 4/6] RUN apt-get update     && apt-get install -y poppler-utils tesseract-ocr     && apt-get clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/  0.3s
------                                                                                                                                                       
 > [worker 4/6] RUN apt-get update     && apt-get install -y poppler-utils tesseract-ocr     && apt-get clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*:            
0.155 Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease [116 kB]                                                                                         
0.173 Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease [48.4 kB]                                                                      
0.184 Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease [44.1 kB]                                                                                
0.213 Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease                                                                                                  
0.213   At least one invalid signature was encountered.
0.248 Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease
0.248   At least one invalid signature was encountered.
0.283 Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease
0.283   At least one invalid signature was encountered.
0.289 Reading package lists...
0.297 W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
0.297 E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease' is not signed.
0.297 W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
0.297 E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease' is not signed.
0.297 W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease: At least one invalid signature was encountered.
0.297 E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease' is not signed.
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update     && apt-get install -y poppler-utils tesseract-ocr     && apt-get clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
juan@192 docwise-backend %
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why i got that error but I ended up increasing the size of space available by Docker.

I am using Docker desktop.

I also notice that if i reset the docker desktop it will also free up space.

it appears that docker desktop has the issue that it hugs a lot of the memory and it does not release the memory back